# How to send a authentication request to /pusher/auth in Pusher API in presence channel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, pusher

I'm working on Pusher API to create a group chat app. I'm having problem to authenticate the user while in presence channel mode. Can anyone point out how exactly an authentication request is sent in the process. If you can,please explain using some code? Use NodeJs

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was getting it all wrong. Pusher library automatically sends authentication request to the authentication endpoints whenever a subscription to the channel(presence/private) is made. So, the answer is there was no need to send the authentication request.